# How to turn the result (in python) of itertools.permutations("0123456789") into list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, permutation, python-itertools

In Python, I am using `list(itertools.permutations("0123456789"))`, and I am receiving (I as expected) a list of tuples of singled character strings.

Is there a way to turn that result into a list of strings, without iterating over all 3628800 items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it *without iterating over the whole list* but rather lazily doing it as needed, you can use `itertools.imap`:

```
itertools.imap(lambda x: "".join(x), itertools.permutations("0123456789"))
```

(note that I'm not using `list()` on the result of `permutations` here so it's as lazy as possible)

Or, as pointed out in the comments, a simple generator expression would work here as well:

```
("".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations("0123456789"))
```

`itertools.imap` has the additional benefit of being able to apply the same function on lots of iterables with a convenient syntax (simply adding them as subsequent arguments), but that's not necessary for this particular usage as we only have one iterable

Comment: Which is hardly better, but less common than a generator expression: `("".join(xs) for xs in itertools.permutations("0123456789"))`. And WhyTF `str.join("")`?

Comment: @delnan Yeah I replaced the `str.join` brainfart, had my head in other languages far too long ;)

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect that fast a reply! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turning it into a list iterates over the whole thing. You can turn it into a list with a list comprehension, which will be better than turning it into a list then iterating over all the items of the list:

```
[''.join(item) for item in itertools.permutations('0123456789')]
```

If you don't need to end up with a list, a generator expression will suffice (replace `[]` with `()`).